# How to install jasmin SMS Gateway the systemd from a Repo

Tags: python, linux, centos, system-administration, jasmin-sms

I have a CentOs7 VPS Server, I want to install Jasmin on it, am quite new to Linux. So I tried the first method but always get the version error. I install the EPEL repo on my CentOs and ran the installation but twice I got this Error

```
Total size: 30 M
Installed size: 80 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test


Transaction check error:
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py from install of python-jasmin-0.9.29-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package pyparsing-1.5.6-9.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing.pyc from install of python-jasmin-0.9.29-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package pyparsing-1.5.6-9.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing.pyo from install of python-jasmin-0.9.29-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package pyparsing-1.5.6-9.el7.noarch

Error Summary
```

Following this Instruction from Jasmin installation code  [Install for RHEL and CENTOS](https://jasmin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/index.html#rhel-centos)

So I decided to use pip [install using PIP](https://jasmin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/index.html#pypi)

And Am stock Here

```
systemd scripts must be downloaded from here <https://github.com/jookies/jasmin/tree/master/misc/config/systemd> and manually installed into your system, once placed in /lib/systemd/system
```

So how do I Carry out this process

So what is wrong with the error produced in the former step.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove pyparsing RPM package to fix "Transaction check error"

Comment: How do I do this